# Can't connect M210 to DJI assistant 2

Tags: dji-sdk

I am trying to connect my drone M210 RTK to DJI assistant 2, but when i connect my drone to the computer, nothing happen.

I have switched on the drone and put the button on the good configuration to connect to a computer by USB cable. I have also made both RTK and M210 firmware update using the remote controller and the DJI GO 4 App.

So here is my problem : How to do to make the M210 RTK available in Dji assistant 2 so i can enable the API.

Answer (score 1):

A few more things to check for you:

1. Are you using the USB cable that came with the Aircraft?
2. Are you using DJI Assistant 2 v1.1.8+?
3. Is the switch on the back to the aircraft to the computer sign? (switch all the way to the left) [image: Switch picture from manual] page 41 in [the manual](https://dl.djicdn.com/downloads/M200/20171024/Matrice_210_210_RTK_User_Manual_EN.pdf)
4. Did you try to reboot your computer. Assistant works with a background binary which establishes the communication with the aircraft, on rare occasions it freezes, you can kill the process but rebooting is easier.
5. Did you try re-pluging the USB cable after power on and switch to computer mode?
6. Can you access the RTK from assistant (usb switch on RTK)?

Comment: Here are the answers to your questions: 1. Yes, I am using the USB cable provided by DJI . 2. I am currently using DJI assistant 1.1.8 and i did'nt see any newer version available. 3. Yes, the switch is toggled on the left. 4. I tried reboot my computer, more thant one time, but did'nt help. 5. I tried this too just now, and did'nt give me results either. 6. Surprising but yes the RTK is available there. I am still available if you need more informations and have an idea to solve my probem, thanks